# Is it possible to deploy a PHP remote git with Cloud Shell in Google cloud?

Tags: php, git, google-app-engine

After reading several webs and google cloud documentation, I start thinking that is not possible to deploy a PHP git repo https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php.git directly from Cloud shell.

In every tutorial, and in the documentation they always say you need the gcloud SDK to run it locally, but how about directly from Cloud shell?

The idea is to make work a PHP hello world example like the one in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/tree/master/1-hello-world but I'm having problems with the runtime. [Official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/hello-world)

> In env: flex, only the following runtimes are allowed:
>   ('python-compat', 'java', 'java7', 'go', 'custom')

After reading I might be missing something related to docker file or composer.json, I did tests with this last one but without success so if there's a way it might be with docker file.

But while I continue investigating I wanted to know if it's possible and if I'm missing something.

Thank you!